# Why Set.add() method does not work in anonymous Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, concurrency

I would like to run 20 threads simultaneously to test my id generator. However, uniqueSet.add(id) is not adding id to the set. When I assert, it says set size is zero.

```
@Test
void should_generate_unique_id_concurrently() throws InterruptedException {
    Set<Long> uniqueSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    final int numberOfThreads = 20;
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfThreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                latch.countDown();
                latch.await();
                long id = idGenerator.nextId();
                uniqueSet.add(id);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    assertEquals(numberOfThreads, uniqueSet.size());
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves the problem, but the test should at least wait until all submitted tasks have been executed. This involves collecting all [`Future<?>`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) returned by [`service.submt(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) and then [`get()`ting](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) the values of all those `Future<?>`s.

Comment: @Turing85 No need for Futures.  `service.shutdown` followed by `service.awaitTermination` will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @VGR Yeah, this works too in this special case.

Answer (score 2):

The `uniqueSet.add(id)` probably is working just fine. But most likely, none of those tasks is able to execute that line before the main thread asks for the size of the set.

Each of your task calls `latch.countDown()` *before* it does anything else. That means, none of the tasks will be able to do anything else until all twenty of them have been started.

Meanwhile, your main thread asks for the size of the set *immediately* after it submits the last task to the thread pool. The main thread already is running at that point. Probably most of the pool threads are sleeping in `latch.await()` The ones that aren't haven't even got that far yet.  The main thread probably always calls `uniqueSet.size()` before any of the worker threads reaches the `uniqueSet.add(id)` line.

---

@VGR suggested a good solution to your problem: After your main thread has submitted the twenty tasks, and before it checks the size of the set, it could shut the thread pool down:

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        service.submit(...);
    }

    // Tell the `service` to refuse new tasks, and to shut down
    // _after_ all of the pending tasks have completed.
    service.shutdown();

    // Wait until all of the tasks have completed.
    service.awaitTermination();

    assertEquals(numberOfThreads, uniqueSet.size());
```

Comment: I followed the steps that you and @VGR mentioned, finally the problem has been solved. Thank you.